# Android app is not deployed on emulator in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I am new to working on android studio. Downloaded the latest version of Android studio, I just wrote a hello world program and when deploying it to emulator, its taking forever.

I did not write any code to check if I went wrong somewhere in my coding.

I can see these in logcat:

```
2019-09-20 10:33:39.010 6159-6276/? W/ErrorProcessor: onFatalError, processing error from engine(4)
com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.speech.b.g: Error reading from input stream
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.j.a.a(SourceFile:28)
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.j.b.run(SourceFile:15)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ax.run(SourceFile:14)
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.bl.run(SourceFile:4)
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.bl.run(SourceFile:4)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ai.run(SourceFile:6)
     Caused by: com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.exception.GsaIOException: Error code: 393238 | Buffer overflow, no available space.
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.Tee.f(SourceFile:103)
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.au.read(SourceFile:2)
    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.ao.run(SourceFile:18)
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.an.run(SourceFile:2)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457) 
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ax.run(SourceFile:14) 
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.bl.run(SourceFile:4) 
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.bl.run(SourceFile:4) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ai.run(SourceFile:6) 
2019-09-20 10:33:39.010 6159-6276/? I/AudioController: internalShutdown
2019-09-20 10:33:39.014 6159-6159/? I/MicroDetector: Keeping mic open: false
2019-09-20 10:33:39.014 6159-6159/? I/MicroDetectionWorker: #onError(false)
2019-09-20 10:33:39.014 6159-6258/? I/DeviceStateChecker: DeviceStateChecker cancelled
2019-09-20 10:33:44.022 6159-6159/? I/MicroDetectionWorker: #updateMicroDetector [detectionMode: [mDetectionMode: [1]]]
2019-09-20 10:33:44.022 6159-6159/? I/MicroDetectionWorker: #startMicroDetector [speakerMode: 0]
2019-09-20 10:33:44.023 6159-6159/? I/AudioController: Using mInputStreamFactoryBuilder
2019-09-20 10:33:44.075 6159-6159/? I/MicroDetectionWorker: onReady
2019-09-20 10:33:44.080 6159-6276/? I/MicroRecognitionRunner: Starting detection.
2019-09-20 10:33:44.080 6159-6266/? I/MicrophoneInputStream: mic_starting com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.aa.c@12afee8
2019-09-20 10:33:44.084 1504-8322/? I/AudioFlinger: AudioFlinger's thread 0xa1783740 tid=8322 ready to run
2019-09-20 10:33:44.089 1504-1639/? E/AudioFlinger: not enough memory for AudioTrack size=131296
2019-09-20 10:33:44.089 1504-1639/? D/MemoryDealer:   AudioTrack (0xa5362030, size=4194304)
    0: 0xa5362040 | 0x00000000 | 0x000200E0 | A 
    1: 0xa5362070 | 0x000200E0 | 0x000200E0 | A 
    2: 0xa53621c0 | 0x000401C0 | 0x000200E0 | A 
    3: 0xa5362090 | 0x000602A0 | 0x000200E0 | A 
    4: 0xa53623f0 | 0x00080380 | 0x000200E0 | A 
    5: 0xa5f1bdc0 | 0x000A0460 | 0x000200E0 | A 
    6: 0xa57b7640 | 0x000C0540 | 0x000200E0 | A 
    7: 0xa53625b0 | 0x000E0620 | 0x000200E0 | A 
    8: 0xa57b7930 | 0x00100700 | 0x000200E0 | A 
    9: 0xa53628c0 | 0x001207E0 | 0x000200E0 | A 
   10: 0xa53622b0 | 0x001408C0 | 0x000200E0 | A 
   11: 0xa57b7c00 | 0x001609A0 | 0x000200E0 | A 
   12: 0xa57b7ae0 | 0x00180A80 | 0x000200E0 | A 
   13: 0xa57b7e10 | 0x001A0B60 | 0x000200E0 | A 
   14: 0xa5362b90 | 0x001C0C40 | 0x000200E0 | A 
   15: 0xa57b7e40 | 0x001E0D20 | 0x000200E0 | A 
   16: 0xa57b7b40 | 0x00200E00 | 0x000200E0 | A 
   17: 0xa45ff0f0 | 0x00220EE0 | 0x000200E0 | A 
   18: 0xa45ff260 | 0x00240FC0 | 0x000200E0 | A 
   19: 0xa45ff3b0 | 0x002610A0 | 0x000200E0 | A 

2019-09-20 10:33:44.089 1504-1639/? E/AudioFlinger: createRecordTrack_l() initCheck failed -12; no control block?
2019-09-20 10:33:44.101 6159-6266/? E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -12
2019-09-20 10:33:44.122 6159-6266/? E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -12.
2019-09-20 10:33:44.122 6159-6266/? E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
2019-09-20 10:33:44.122 6159-6266/? I/MicrophoneInputStream: mic_started com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.aa.c@12afee8
2019-09-20 10:33:44.123 6159-6159/? I/MicroDetectionWorker: onReady
2019-09-20 10:33:44.133 6159-6266/? I/MicrophoneInputStream: mic_close com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.aa.c@12afee8
2019-09-20 10:33:44.133 6159-6276/? I/MicroRecognitionRunner: Detection finished
2019-09-20 10:33:44.133 6159-6276/? W/ErrorReporter: reportError [type: 211, code: 524300]: Error reading from input stream
2019-09-20 10:33:44.134 6159-6299/? I/MicroRecognitionRunner: Stopping hotword detection.
2019-09-20 10:33:44.135 6159-6276/? W/ErrorProcessor: onFatalError, processing error from engine(4)
com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.speech.b.g: Error reading from input stream
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.j.a.a(SourceFile:28)
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.j.b.run(SourceFile:15)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ax.run(SourceFile:14)
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.bl.run(SourceFile:4)
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.bl.run(SourceFile:4)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ai.run(SourceFile:6)
 Caused by: com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.exception.GsaIOException: Error code: 393238 | Buffer overflow, no available space.
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.Tee.f(SourceFile:103)
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.au.read(SourceFile:2)
    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.ao.run(SourceFile:18)
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.an.run(SourceFile:2)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457) 
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ax.run(SourceFile:14) 
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.bl.run(SourceFile:4) 
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.bl.run(SourceFile:4) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ai.run(SourceFile:6)
```

These logs are in repetitive mode. What is that I am missing here? I have HAXM installed.

Comment: did you see my answer?

Answer (score 0):

The logcat says this error:

> Caused by:
>   com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.exception.GsaIOException: Error
>   code: 393238 | Buffer overflow, no available space.

Did you have enough space on disk for the emulator?

Or may be a permission for audio recording needed in the manifest, so try adding this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

You can also try to completely quit the emulator, without saving the state, and restart it.